# VS2010 Remote debugger stopping where is no breakpoint

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging, debugbreak

I am remotely debugging a dll (C++, unmanaged) for Microsoft FSX (I do not know whether this matters). The dll is compiled as "Multi-threaded-dll", since it does not work as "Multi-threaded-dll debug". My dll currently just contains a `DllStart` and `DllStop` function, this is standard in FSX.

I general debugging works (it stops at my breakpoints), but somehow the debugger also stops in places where I did **not** place a breakpoint. First the issue came up in the "NO Source available" flavor. After checking

1. [Suppress "No Source Available" pane in 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672153/suppress-no-source-available-pane-in-2010) and
2. [No Source available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806993/no-source-available)

the only solution working for me was to install the mentioned [extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fdbb2036-471e-40a7-b20e-31f8fd5578fa/). Now I do not get the "No source" tab anymore, but debugger still stops somewhere outside my code. I have cleaned all breakpoints as recommended in " [Debugger stops when there is no breakpoint VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896820/debugger-stops-when-there-is-no-breakpoint-vs2010) ".
[image: Stopping in VS2010]
`bglmanx.dll` is another dll, also started by FSX. I was thinking, OK, maybe there is some ambiguity about the symbols and have renamed my functions to `DllStartFSXM` and `DllStopFSXM` (and hence being unique). No improvement.

Any ideas, hints?

Comment: Can you continue the application when the debugger stops on its own? If not, this might actually be a bug in the dll, like a crash that only happens in debug mode.

Comment: Yes, I can continue. Eventually it crashes FSX  (only when debugging, without it is just fine), but it is not my DLL (I can tell, because it happens even if the functions are empty bodies). This is why I need to get around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be caused by having __asm int 3 or a DebugBreak in the other code?

Perhaps there is some way of disabling these commands or reimplmenting the DebugBreak function?